# Simple gradle build file build error

Tags: build, gradle

I am trying out several gradle basics.
Here is how my gradle file "build.gradle" looked:

```
task hello
{
    doLast
    {
        println 'Hello World!'
    }
}
```

This causes the following error:

```
D:\DevAreas\learn-gradle>gradle -q hello

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\DevAreas\learn-gradle\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'D:\DevAreas\learn-gradle\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'D:\DevAreas\learn-gradle\build.gradle': 2: Ambiguous expression could be a parameterle
ss closure expression, an isolated open code block, or it may continue a previous statement;
   solution: Add an explicit parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to be treated as an open
block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...}, and also either remove the previous newline, or add an exp
licit semicolon ';' @ line 2, column 1.
     {
     ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more l
og output.
```

If I make a minor modification to the build file like so

> [Please NOTE that I have moved the parenthesis from second line to
>   first line]

```
task hello{
    doLast
    {
        println 'Hello World!'
    }
}
```

I see the output

```
Hello World!
```

with out issues.

Is parenthesis such a big problem in gradle? What was I doing so wrong by placing the parenthesis in the second line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with other languages that use semicolon inference, the newline makes a difference in Groovy. The first snippet gets parsed as `task hello; { ... }`, which is ambiguous (can't decide if the second statement is a block or a closure) and hence invalid Groovy syntax. It's not what you want anyway; you want the closure to be associated with the `hello` task. To avoid such surprises, I recommend to follow the Java braces style.

Comment: I guess this should be written in the Groovy documentation and brought fourth as a point in training sessions.