# Android build.gradle bracing style bug

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.1

This is my top-level "build.gradle" file for my Android Studio (2.1.2) project, which I'm developing on a Mac.

```
buildscript
{
    repositories
    {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies
    {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects
{
    repositories
    {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Everything works fine until I change that bottom "task clean" block to use the same bracing style, like so.

```
task clean(type: Delete)
{
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If I make this change and click on "sync now" in the upper-right corner, I get a syntax error on the left curly-brace line below the word "task".

> Error:(28, 0) Cause: startup failed:
>   build file 'build.gradle': 28: Ambiguous expression could be a parameterless closure expression, an isolated open code block, or it may continue a previous statement;
>      solution: Add an explicit parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to be treated as an open block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...}, and also either remove the previous newline, or add an explicit semicolon ';' @ line 28, column 1.
>      {
>      ^

Is this a bug in Android Studio, Gradle, or...?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in this stack overflow post, the problem is semicolon inference.

[Simple gradle build file build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385342/simple-gradle-build-file-build-error)

So the solution in my case is to use this syntax.

```
task clean(type: Delete) \
{
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```